# System tick timer interrupt priority and blocked interrupts

Tags: operating-systems, interrupts, timer

Assume we have an OS that is running on a CPU which is fully compatible with its requirements. This OS is tick driven. System tick interrupt arrive from external timer (periodic mode) which is connected to some CPU IRQn pin for simplicity.

IRQ pins are sorted by interrupt priority. IRQ0 has the highest priority and IRQn has the lowest priority. Priority is there at least for two reasons. First one is of course when arrive two interrupts together, one with higher priority is selected. The second reason is following: when interrupt occurs, further interrupts are disabled by hardware. When interrupts are in ISR enabled (possible nesting interrupts), only interrupts with higher priority can occurs. And I have some questions about it.

My first question is probably really simple and I can answer it by myself (maybe), but I want to read reliable answer.

- **How to choose timer tick priority? Is it the lowest interrupt priority in the system?***

Here is the second question.

- **What if timer tick interrupt occurs exactly while CPU is serving another interrupt(s) and further interrupts are disabled?**

And here is addition by me. If can happen the above situation (in the second question), there is a chance to lost system tick. Can it cause any big problems?

*If timer tick priority wasn't the lowest interrupt priority in the system, it may occurs situation when CPU is in ISR with lower priority than system tick interrupt and enables further interrupts and user process, that we need for potentially scheduling, is stored somewhere on the stack, where we can't find it in system tick routine.

I know that it all can be system-dependent, but I am interested in any typical solutions that are similary to this situation.

Sorry for my English.

Comment: Your mixing a lot of different [questions](http://superuser.com/questions/1012978/system-tick-timer-interrupt-in-smp) and ideas;  `How to choose timer tick priority?` depends completely on you and what you're building, especially if you're talking about CPU interrupts (which is highly system dependent) .. What exactly are you trying to do? Also, you might get a better response on a different StackExchange site (like StackOverflow) ..

Comment: @txtechhelp Thank you for your time. I wrote it. I am looking for any, really ANY, typical solutions that are similar to this situation. For example Linux with arm architecture. Or with x86. Or select conditions completly by yourself. It can be even long answer.