# System tick timer interrupt in SMP

Tags: cpu, multi-processor, timer

Is system tick timer interrupt in SMP system synchronized among CPUs/cores? If not, how is it solved?*

Sorry for my English.

**EDIT:**
With system tick timer interrupt I mean interrupt from system timer that is used by operating system. No CPU frequency clock source.

*I am interested in typical solve of this/similar problem.

Comment: No problem with the language, but _which exact problem_ has to be solved in your opinion? And what kind of multi-CPU system are you talking about?

Comment: Are you meaning the core clock of the system (i.e. the bus clock), or are you talking about the "monotonic" time of the system (i.e. ticks since epoch)? Either way, yes, data and clocks are synchronized among the cores .. how depends on the architecture and many other things .. what specifically were you trying to figure out?

Comment: Thank you for your time. Required information has been added.

Comment: It's still not clear to me where you deem a problem there. On multicore machines, there's still only one operating system running, and it maintains a centraised model of resources where required -- there's usually only one clock in the system.

Comment: It's all about system tick interrupt. There is question about that if the wire from external timer, that we for instance select as a system timer, is signaled on all cores/CPUs concurrently and every core/CPU executes system timer routine or there are one timer per core or only one core execute this routine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In modern day and age, there are *[tickless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tickless_kernel)* kernels, which do not have static tickrates. They calculate the time until they *have* to interrupt again and program the [APIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Programmable_Interrupt_Controller) (which regulates Interrupts) accordingly.

Windows 10 uses a tickless kernel and the option exists for Linux as well. A tickless kernel increases the throughput of the system (due to less interruptions, less context switches, etc) at the cost of longer response times.

In a tickless environment, every kernel (thus core) takes care about this himself. Synchronizity between cores is not a necessity for a stable environment and the answer to your question simply is:

It depends on the implementation.